# WebSocket supported in Android Stock Browser or not?

Tags: javascript, android, websocket

using https://github.com/einaros/ws

Server:

```
var WebSocketServer=require('ws').Server,wss=new WebSocketServer({port:8004});

wss.on('connection',function(s) {
    s.on('message',function(_){console.log('received: '+_);});
});
```

Client:

```
var s=new WebSocket('ws://mysite.com:8004');
//android default browser dies here <---------------?       
s.onopen=function(){
    $('body').css({'background':'green'});
    s.send('hi');
    };
```

I have to ask why android default browser does not open the connection?

I visit www.websocket.org/echo.html on the default android browser and it says **This browser supports websocket.** so what is the problem?

This simple code works on iphone safari, windows chrome, android mobile chrome no problem.

On android default browser I can also console.dir(window.WebSocket); and it shows the WebSocket Object no differently than other browsers.

If someone knows why, please tell.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

```
if (!window.WebSocket && window.MozWebSocket) {
    window.WebSocket = window.MozWebSocket;
    alert('MozWebSocket');
}
else if (!window.WebSocket) {
    alert("WebSocket not supported by this browser");
}
else{
    alert('wtf!? '+window.WebSocket);
}
```

This gives me a console log of:

```
wtf!? function WebSocket(){[native code]}
```

Comment: What version of Android? On my 2.3 device, I see `window.WebSocket` as `undefined`. Maybe whatever page you were testing on has a `WebSocket` polyfill?

Comment: Android version 4.1.2

Comment: If `Websocket` is indeed defined in your browser, maybe it's failing because uses an older protocol. (Also, http://caniuse.com/websockets indicates that WebSockets came to the Android default browser in the 4.4 release. If you do have `WebSocket` in a non-4.4 browser, maybe that table is a reflection of a lack of modern WS protocol support.)

Comment: just tried ws protocol 8 but no change

Comment: Your stated browser (Android Browser 4.1.2), and your stated results, are at odds.  Hit [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/) and include the User Agent of your problematic browser in your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Android stock browser does not, in fact, support WebSocket.

Some work was apparently done in preparation for adding support, so the API in the browser is there, i.e. you can create a WebSocket object. It's just that this doesn't actually do anything behind the scenes.

This results in a simple feature support check, which just attempts to create the socket object, showing WebSocket support. Check the readyState for a created WebSocket object instead, and you'll see that this never changes from "0".

Starting with Android 4.4, there is no stock browser anymore. The Web view component has been switched to Chrome for Android - and this does support WebSocket.

Comment: How then can one make an app that uses websockets so that it is backwards compatible for older android devices?

Comment: You either need to add WS supoort via something like flash bridge (like https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js), or use HTTP fallback (polling/long-polling). There are libraries out there which provide this (such as http://socket.io/).

Comment: That's why cross-mobile development is still a PITA!

Comment: I have Android 4.4 and a stock browser that is definitely not Chrome for Android... What you describe is exactly what happens though. A WebSocket dud. Funny sssholes.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, now Android stock browser supports WebSocket: http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets

Comment: I know this is old, but nowadays, Chrome on Android does support websockets fully. You can just open this page on your device to verify it: websocketstest.com